# showed that $x^2 + y^2$ = $1$ if ...........

Tags: trigonometry

Please help me .how can I solve this problem:
If $x \sin^3 \alpha$ + $y \cos^3 \alpha$ = $\sin\alpha\cos\alpha$          and            $x \sin\alpha-y\cos\alpha$ = $0$  then showed that $x^2 + y^2$ = $1$

Comment: Have you tried expressing $x,y$ in terms of the polar coordinates, i.e. $x= r \cos \theta, y= r \sin \theta$?

Comment: This is false: take $x=y=\sin\alpha=0$. This is true if $\sin\alpha\cos\alpha\neq 0$, in which case you can solve the linear system and find $x=...$, and $y=...$

Comment: Just solve for $x,y$ from the simultaneous equations.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the fact that (from your second equation) $x\sin\alpha = y \cos \alpha$, and substitute that into the left-hand side of the first equation. What does this tell you about $y$? What happens if you then re-substitute this into the second equation?

Answer (score 0):

from the second equation, you get $y = x\tan \alpha$

Substitute this in first equation and you will get $x = \cos \alpha$
which means $y= \sin \alpha$

$$x^2+y^2 = \sin^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \alpha = 1$$

proved

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Prove that $x^2+y^2=\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha$=1.